# Extract images with rarfile and django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying extract images from archive and save images in django model

```
    with rarfile.RarFile(archive) as rf:
        for name in rf.namelist():
           image = rf.open(name)
               fimg = FarcopImages.objects.create(scheme=image, article=article)
               fimg.save()
```

Error:

```
'PipeReader' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: Can you show your models.py code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save a `RarFile`-esque file instance to your model. You need to use the built-in django `File` object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/files/#the-file-object

```
# Something like...
from django.core.files import File

# ...

with rf.open(name) as file_like_object:
    FarcopImages.objects.create(scheme=File(file_like_object), article=article)
```